# Javascript Regex to validate numerical characters having - (dash) between them

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I am trying to validate the following format with the Javascript Regex
Basically the first set of number before the dash must be 3 numeric characters only.
Whereas the characters after dash can be either two or three numeric characters only.
No other characters or spaces are allowed.

I have seen several articles on javascript Regex but all of them were pretty basic and no 
where near to satisfying the criteria below. The complex ones went way over my head.
Anyone got a javascript regex for this?

```
089-02  Valid 
043-342 Valid 
03-22   Invalid
023-23  Valid
021-0123 Invalid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var test = "213-12";

console.log(/^\d{3}-\d{2,3}$/.test(test)); // true
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TTNfE/1/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

`/^\d{3}-\d{2,3}$/`

The regex is explained [here](http://regex101.com/r/nB0vM7)

Comment: @Sike12, do you want to match just a single one ?

Comment: @Amit Both the solutions provided work. All i wanted to was to get the Regex to perform the validation above.

Comment: @Sike12 Both solutions are the same, this answer shouldn't be posted because it's duplicate, but anyways ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex pattern for the desired result  /\d{3}-\d{2,3}$/